# Shopware 6 - Composite primary key with columns of multiple types, in entity definition

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, shopware, shopware6

Here is the **problem description**:

I created a custom entity and a definition for it.
The defineFields function body is this:

```
protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection {
    return new FieldCollection([
        (new FkField('product_family_id', 'productFamilyId', ProductFamilyDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
        (new StringField('area_id', 'areaId'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
        (new StringField('block_number', 'blockNumber'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
        (new StringField('text', 'text')),
        new CreatedAtField(),
        new UpdatedAtField(),
        (new ManyToOneAssociationField('productFamily', 'product_family_id', ProductFamilyDefinition::class, 'id')),
    ]);
}
```

So, as you can see, we need to have a composite primary key of `product_family_id`, `area_id` and `block_number`. The thing is, the fields `area_id` and `block_number` need to be of type string. But because the `PrimaryKey()` flags were added to those fields, Shopware doesn't want to perform insert operations because shopware now wants the two fields to have UUID length (16 characters). If we remove the `PrimaryKey()` flag then `area_id` and `block_number` fields can have whichever size, as they should.

An example of a request / response operation for this problem is to be found here:

**Example request:**

```
URL: http://localhost/api/_action/sync
BODY: [{"entity":"product_family_additional_info","action":"upsert","payload":[{"productFamilyId":"cb5e21bda1d8488ab5dda9d3fb4e4fe4","areaId":"22","blockNumber":"33","text":"text121"}]}]
```

**Example response:**

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "result": [
                {
                    "entities": [],
                    "errors": [
                        {
                            "status": "400",
    

                    "code": "FRAMEWORK__UUID_INVALID_LENGTH",
                        "title": "Bad Request",
                        "detail": "UUID has a invalid length. 16 bytes expected, 2 given. Hexadecimal reprensentation: 3232",
                        "meta": {
                            "parameters": {
                                "length": 2,
                                "hex": "3232"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "extensions": []
    }
],
"deleted": [],
"notFound": [],
"extensions": []
}
```

**So, is there  way to have a composite primary key with columns of multiple types? And when we add the PrimaryKey() flag, the column not to be forced to be of UUID length.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopware expects that `PrimaryKey` fields are Uuids, but in your case you could add a own IdField to your definition and in the Database migration that creates the table you can add a unique constraint for the 3 fields you currently want to use as a composite primary key.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I've done. I don't think there is another way around. I will open an issue to Shopware though. Probably they will consider it